# I need help installing Linux Mint 18 on a computer with Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint

Here's what happened.

1. I shut down my computer.
2. I turned off Secure Boot
3. I put in my (authentic) Linux Mint installation disk into my disk drive
4. I checked the integrity of the media.  No errors found.
5. I started Linux Mint.
6. Linux took a long time to start, and then froze on me before it even finished.
7. I went into compatibility mode to check on what was wrong.
8. The computer told me that the metadata of my hard drive was in Windows cache.
9. I shrunk the main partition of my hard drive.
10. I shut down the computer again.  (I didn't simply turn it off.)
11. I booted into the disk again.
12. Attempted to start Linux in Compatibility Mode.
13. Told me the NTFS partition I opened up by shrinking the system's main partition was in an unsafe state because I needed to resume Windows and fully shut it down.
14. I tried many things again and again with little success.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn off an option called **Fast Startup**.

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Go to Power options.
3. Click on the option "Choose what the power buttons do" in the top left corner.
   [image]
4. Click on "Change settings that are not currently available option".
   [image]
5. Uncheck "Turn on Fast startup".
   [image]

---

**What is Fast startup?**

> Starting with Windows 8, a fast startup mode is available to start a
>   computer in less time than is typically required for a traditional,
>   cold startup. A fast startup is a hybrid combination of a cold startup
>   and a wake-from-hibernation startup.

The fast startup enables to start windows faster by using a hibernation like technology. But this means that Windows is not properly shutdown. It is more or like hibernation. Hence the error message "Resume Windows and fully shut it down". Disable fast startup and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

When Windows has Hibernate enabled, it writes a file to HDD, hiberfil.sys, that contains the state of the system on shutdown, and it may mark the disk as currently in use. As a safety to prevent loss of data, Linux is refusing to boot.

To get rid of hiberfil.sys *safely*, restart Windows 10 and completely turn off hibernation with the following command in a CMD prompt started with administrative privilege:

> powercfg -h off

You might put that, and the converse,

> powercfg -h on

into two batch scripts, and create shortcuts to them to be run as Administrator, to make turning Hibernate on and off more convenient in a ual boot system.

After Hibernate mode is disabled, you can then continue the Linux distro installation.